build a jenkins job using a local repository (folder)
I'm new using Jenkins and all the answers that i've seen in the internet doesn't help me at all.
Basically: I have a local folder that contains a dockerfile and all the files i need to run inside the docker container. I need to create a job that runs this container in the jenkins pipeline. I already have a Jenkinsfile... I need to run it locally because I don't have permission to run the Jenkinsfile of my work, so my boss told me to build one for myself to learn from it...
Can someone help me,  please?
Tried running from the Bitbucket repository and failed, now i am trying to run it locally.
